# Adding two text labels (one dynamic and one static) in the same table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, textlabel

I have a tableview with custom cells inside a view controller. My tableview works properly. What I am trying to do is develop the image below programmatically. Where "label" is the  text that is custom and changes depending on some input. How can I include these 2 labels (in cellForRowAtIndexPath:) and determine their position in the cell.
Image contains 2 different table cells.

[image: Image contains 2 different table cells]

I am aware how to do it through storyboard, but I need to do it programmatically cause I am using dynamic cells in xCode 4.5.

The image refers to the index cells 1 and 2. I have only managed to include one text label per cell till now.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}




    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {
           // image cell - image resize and centred


            UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,2, 180, 180)];
            imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"test1.jpg"];


            imv.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];

            imv.center = CGPointMake(cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2,cell.contentView.bounds.size.height/2);

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {


            cell.textLabel.text = @"Name";


            break;
        }

        case 2:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Manufacturer";

            break;
        }

        case 3:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Overall Score";

            break;
        }

        case 4:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Description";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

            break;
        }

        case 5:
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Videos";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

            break;
        }
            }


    return cell;

}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: you should include something like what you've tried, code, etc just so people know what you don't know/understand

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added the part of code I need help with. @believesInSanta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the default UITableViewCell styles first: UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
   UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
   UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle.

If you can use them, you don't need to subclass UITableViewCell.  Otherwise you're going to have to do just that and put 3 properties down: a UIView and 2 UILabel's.  The reason is if you don't use default cell styles, you cannot move or add cell elements.

Your UITableViewCell subclass should have the following code:

```
@interface UITableViewCellSubClass : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label2;
@end

@implementation UITableViewCellSubClass
@synthesize view;
@synthesize label1;
@synthesize label2;
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [self addSubview:view];
    // initiate label1 with position (10,10,150,20)
    label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,150,20)];
    // initiate label2 with position (170,10,150,20)
    label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170,10,150,20)];
    [view addSubview:label1];
    [view addSubview:label2];
}
return self;
}
@end
```

Then you can return that in your cellForRowAtIndex: method and basically:

```
UITableViewCellSubclass *cell = [[UITableViewCellSubclass alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[cell.label1 setText:@"text"];
[cell.label2 setText:@"more text"];
```

Hope this helps and don't forget to #import "UITableViewCellSubClass.h"

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for late reply acceptance but I was away. Thank you again

Comment: Can I ask you something in addition. If I don't want all cells have the same content/tableviewcell subclass, what is the easiest way to do it through cellForRowAtIndex?

Comment: you can use different tableviewcell subclasses as long as they have different reuse identifiers, or you create one yourself all the possible UILabels, UIButtons, etc with a type property that'll dictate the position, etc

Comment: Thank you. Why when I use your code it says No visible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector addSubView

Comment: probably because you should change it to addSubview